# I'm trying to make an image after using UV editor to unwrap it, but the previous image is coming up and the quality of the paint brush is pixelated

Tags: image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Ok so what I'm trying to do is draw the right arm right. So now I try to make a new image file for the second arm that way i can draw but even after I make one it goes to the other arm's file. Furthermore it does the same when i go to uv editor and select the new arm and project from view. I need some help pls if someone could explain. Or if you can walk me through step by step im live on twitch making it at https://twitch.tv/dashadowman_
[image: low pixelated brush][image: issue seeing on the image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing the UV workspace with the object in edit mode with all faces selected and a screenshot of your material nodegroups.  Also, is it possible that you have multiple objects showing in the scene?